# Nodejs application overloading CPU

Tags: node.js, pm2

I am facing a CPU overload issue due to a nodejs application that I am running in a remote Ubuntu 16.04 LTS virtual machine. I am using PM2 to schedule my nodejs application as a service.

Initially when the nodejs application is launched, the CPU load remain quite low; about 30% at most. Then slowly I find the CPU load going up till it gets to 100%. This nodejs application is polling a stock website for new information on a stock and then does some calculations and then repeats after 5 minutes. I dont see how its causing this overload on the CPU.

I notice that my 1 nodejs application shows up as 6 different processes in HTOP command. Not sure if this normal or how to fix this. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Regards,

Adeel

[image: Initial Screenshot of HTOP command]

[image: Screenshot 1 hour later of HTOP command]

Comment: A "ps -ef | grep node" would provide additional information.  First guess would be that guardian.js never ends, and you start a new one every 5 minutes.  A copy of "guardian.js" would help.

Comment: According to HTOP, after one hour the master process used 20 minutes of CPU.  That is not bad, not bad at all.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, Gerard. Your reply helped solve the problem. Turns out guardian.js was not exiting and just opening up new processes till it overloaded the system.